# Create new item workflow with the reference to the third list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

(I don't even know if this is possible)
I need to create a new item in the list, but the trick is I have three lists:
List1 - Dates, List2 - items, List3 - PlantsNumbers. So the desired scenario is: when a new item is created in List1 -> New items should be created in the List2 and there should be as many items as I have in List3. 
Example: I have 5 plants in the List3: A001, A002, A003, A004, A005. When I create a new item in List1, I need a workflow to create 5 new items in List2 with A001 -A005 as title. Lists 2 and 3 are connected by look up column - plant Number. 
We have SP 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create additional columns in List1 nd List2 lets say - list1ID and list2ID.
 Create a workflow in List1 with Start Option - Item is created (WF1)

> - Create varID and set varID = 1 (or any whichever is your first item in List3)
> - Steps ->  Create item in List2, with fields - Title (from List3 for ID=varID)  and list2ID = varID and remaining fields as required.

Create a workflow in List2 with Start Option - Item is created (WF2)

> - Steps ->  Calculate list2ID +1 and save to calc variable Update Item in List1 : field is list1ID to value calc

Create a workflow in List1 with Start Option - Item is changed (WF3)

> - Steps -> If(List3(Title) for ID=list1ID) is not empty Create item in List2, Title is List3 Title where ID = list1ID, other fields as
>     required and list2ID = list1ID

So, when a new item is created in List1, WF1 will create the first item in List2. 
WF2 will update the item in List1.
WF3 will create the next item in List2. 
This process continues untill there is no item left in List3

Answer (score 0):

Count number of items in List3, and add a loop to create new item in List2, using List3 Datasource with incrementing ID at the end untill you reach the last ID.

Comment: Great idea! But is there a way to do it with Designer 2010 workflows without loops? We don't have 2013 workflows in production.

Comment: Couldn't update it in the comment, so posted as answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Moved everything in Pilot to test this solution with loop and stuck with problem: List1 and List3 are not connected in any way, and i can't do a lookup there, so when try to build a dictionary to use in count i have no clue what to put into that Find the List Item part of the workflow lookup.

Comment: I thought you were using 2010 designer?

Comment: Yes, we have 2010 in production, but 2013 in Pilot environment, so i tried this in pilot - moved all my lists there.

Comment: Oh ok. The answer posted before was for 2010, if you want to give a try.
For 2013, you will have to build dictionary, call web service to List3 and find the count of items to use it for loop.
Probably the below article, will help you in the steps
http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013